# "[boringssl] boringssl_metrics_log_metric_block_invoke(153) Failed to log metrics 804" error while making networking calls (API requests)

Tags: xcode

I am using openWeather Api to get the data but Xcode shows this `[boringssl] boringssl_metrics_log_metric_block_invoke(153) Failed to log metrics 804` error when I try to make any API request. Lots of different websites says that it is because of iPhone simulator because its not a perfect replica of an iPhone. But there must be any way to avoid this error and get the data. I am using iPhone 11 simulator.